# What does this statement in the 1978 Constitution of the Russian SFSR mean?

Tags: constitution, russian-federation, communism, history

I didn't know where to ask this question, so I am asking it here since it does involve politics to some extent.

[Full Constitution (In Russian)](http://constitution.garant.ru/history/ussr-rsfsr/1978/red_1978/5478722/)

***Here is the statement***

**In Russian:**

Статья 147. Исполнительные комитеты местных Советов народных депутатов руководят государственным, хозяйственным и социально-культурным строительством на территории соответствующих Советов на основе решений избравших их Советов и вышестоящих органов государственной власти и управления.

**Translated to English (using Google Translate):**

Article 147. The executive committees of local Soviets of People's Deputies direct the state, economic, social and cultural development in the territory of the relevant Council on the basis of their decision to elect the Soviets and the higher bodies of state power and administration.

***Question***

I am having trouble understanding what this exactly means. It says "on the basis of the decisions of the Soviet that elected them and the higher bodies of state power and administration"  Now, the constitution makes a clear distinction between decisions, orders, decrees, laws, etc. So, I was wondering, does this encompass all of those things or just "decisions" adopted by higher bodies, because, for example, the Council of Ministers is empowered to issue decisions and orders. Does this mean the the local executive committees only exercise their powers based on the Council of Ministers's decisions, and not its orders?
I hope that isn't confusing, but I have been trying to figure this out for like a month now. Thanks :)

Comment: I believe you'll probably need a proper translator, as Google is not up to the task of translating something that long.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of "Now, the constitution makes a clear distinction between decisions, orders, decrees, laws, etc"? At first glance, I didn't see meaningful delineation.

Comment: @user4012 the Constitution says, for example, that the Council of Ministers can issue "decisions and orders"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In USSR there was a *double subordination principle*. That is, the local executive comittee was subordinated *both* to a local Soviet of People's Deputies (i.e. local legislative body), and to a higher executive comittee (or to the Council of Ministers; i.e. to a higher executive body).

This article actually states that a local executive comittee rules the state on the basis of "*the decisions of local legislative body*" and "*[the decisions, orders, decrees or whatever of] higher executive bodies*". Though the wording is awful, I admit.

So the answer on your question is *definitely both decisions and orders*.

Comment: It actually says "higher bodies of state power (Soviets) and administration bodies (executive bodies)", not just higher executive bodies

Comment: @Jay Well, that was rather an explanation than translation. USSR did not follow the principle of separation of powers, so Constitution mentions "Soviets" and "administrative bodies" instead of "legislative" and "executive" powers.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong translation, apparently. My translation:

> Article 147. The executive committees of local Councils of People's
>   Deputies direct the state, economic, social and cultural development
>   in the territory of the relevant Council on the basis of the decisions
>   of the Councils that elected them and the higher bodies of state power
>   and administration.

Now to your question:

> So, I was wondering, does this encompass all of those things or just
>   "decisions" adopted by higher bodies

Yes, I think so, it does.

Comment: as in yes it does mean all of those things or as in yes it means just decisions?

Comment: @Jay all the things.